# How to refactor (if / elsif / elsif) chain in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I have a chain of `if` / `else if` statement that are not self explanatory. I would like to extract each into its own function with a clear explanatory name and then chain those functions.

How can I stop the call-chain mid-way in scala ?

Here is a code example :

```
// actual code 

for( klass <- program.classes ) {
    if ( complicated boolean ) { //checkVars
        error1
    } else if ( complicated boolean ) { //checkMethods
        error2
    } else if ( ... ) { //...
        error3
    } else {
        complicated good case code
    }
}
```

---

```
// wanted 

for( klass <- program.classes ) {
    (checkName 
     andThen checkVars
     andThen checkMethods
     andThen addToContext) (klass)
// where the chaining stops if a check fails
}
```

Comment: What is the desired action in an error case? Do want to throw an exception, print something and move on, output an error object?

Comment: print something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently I had the same annoying multiple *if-else* block which looked terrible
I come up with the next options:

**Option 1:**
The simplest approach is to introduce a separate function for each *if-else* block, for an example condition I'm just comparing an integer constant with a literal, but you can substitute it with anything else

```
val x = 3

def check1: Option[String] = {
  if (x == 1) Some("error 1") else None
}

def check2: Option[String] = {
  if (x == 2) Some("error 2") else None
}

def check3: Option[String] = {
  if (x == 3) Some("error 3") else None
}

// we can chain Option results together
// using "orElse" function
val result = check1
  .orElse(check2)
  .orElse(check3)

// result contains a returned value from one
// of the above functions,
// or if no checks worked, it ends up with "Option.None"
println(result.getOrElse("passed"))
```

Refactored code as it is, looks much better than multiple *if-else* statements, now we can give each function a reasonable name, and, in my case, it eliminated cyclomatic complexity warnings from style checker

**Option 2:**
The first approach still had "else" part and I wanted to get rid of it at all costs, so I used partial functions

```
// just an alias, so I don't need to write
// the full parameter type for every function
type Validator = PartialFunction[Int, Option[String]]

def check1: Validator = { case x if x == 1 => Some("error 1") }
def check2: Validator = { case x if x == 2 => Some("error 2") }
def check3: Validator = { case x if x == 3 => Some("error 3") }
def default: Validator = { case _ => None }

// we can chain together partial functions
// the same way as we did with Option type
val result = check1
  .orElse(check2)
  .orElse(check3)
  .orElse(default) {
    3 // this is an actual parameter for each defined function
  }

// the result is Option
// if there was an error we get Some(error)
// otherwise the result is Option.None in which case
// we return "passed"
println(result.getOrElse("passed"))
```

Here we can use normal function names as well and we got rid of else's part thanks to the design of the partial function. The only thing is that if there is a need to add another check (one more *if-else* block), it should be added in 2 spots: function declaration and as a new *.orElse* function call

**Option 3:**
It is easy to notice that all the above partial functions can be added in a *List*

```
type Validator = PartialFunction[Int, Option[String]]

val validations: List[Validator] = List(
  { case x if x == 1 => Some("error 1") },
  { case x if x == 2 => Some("error 2") },
  { case x if x == 3 => Some("error 3") },
  { case _ => None }
)
```

Then *List* can be traversed and *.orElse* function can be applied during the traversal. It should be done in any way, I chose the *foldLeft* function

```
val result = validations.tail.foldLeft(validations.head)(_.orElse(_)) {
  3
}

println(result.getOrElse("passed"))
```

Now if we need one more check function to add, it can be done only at one spot - another element of the *List*

**Option 4:**
Another option I wanted to share is that it is also possible to override *PartialFunction* trait by anonymous class and implement its 2 methods: *isDefinedAt* and *apply*

```
type Validator = PartialFunction[Int, Option[String]]

val check1 = new Validator {
  override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = x == 1
  override def apply(v1: Int): Option[String] = Some("error 1")
}

val check2 = new Validator {
  override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = x == 2
  override def apply(v1: Int): Option[String] = Some("error 2")
}

val check3 = new Validator {
  override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = x == 3
  override def apply(v1: Int): Option[String] = Some("error 3")
}

val default = new Validator {
  override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = true
  override def apply(v1: Int): Option[String] = None
}
```

Then we can chain those functions the same way we did in the 2nd option

```
val result = check1
  .orElse(check2)
  .orElse(check3)
  .orElse(default) {
    3
  }

println(result.getOrElse("passed"))
```

Comment: very nice stuff you got here

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Option` type and methods that return `Option[_]` in a `for` comprehension to chain verifications while extracting partial results. Processing stops when an option returns None

```
for {
    klass <- program.classes
    name <- checkName // Option[String]
    vars <- checkVars // Option[SomeType]
    methods <- checkMethods // Option[SomeOtherT]
    ctx <- addToContext // Option[...]
} {
// do something with klass
// if you got here, all the previous Options returned Some(_)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about it, but it annoys me because the checks are not supposed to return anything. I'm not sure the code would be easy to understand if they returned a dummy value. +1 for the good idea though

Comment: Maybe I'm partial to my own solution :-) but in Scala most things return something, because if they do not, they operate by side-effect, and that is against "The Commandments" (the "best practices").

Comment: If you do not like extracting a value, you may extract... a `Unit`. Indeed, `Option[Unit]` has two possible values `Some(())` and `None`, just like `Boolean`, and for comprehension allows you to continue checking other properties while the preceding ones return `Some(())`. Note that, since you don't care about the value (which will always be `()`), you may put `_` on the lhs of every `<-` in your `for` block.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on what you want to happen on an error but this seems like a good case for chained maps using options:

```
def checkName(klass: Klass): Option[Klass] = if (compBoolean) Some(klass) else None
def checkVars(klass: Klass): Option[Klass] = if (compBoolean) Some(klass) else None
def checkMethods(klass: Klass): Option[Klass] = if (compBoolean) Some(klass) else None
def finalOp(klass: Klass): OutputClass = //your final operation

// Use the above checks
program.classes.map(checkName(_).flatMap(checkVars).flatMap(checkMethods).map(finalOp).getOrElse(defaultResult))
```

If you want to skip/omit elements which fail all of your checks then you would use a `flatMap`:

```
program.classes.flatMap(checkName(_).flatMap(checkVars).flatMap(checkMethods).map(finalOp))
```

Comment: I was annoyed by the fact that the checks return a value, but eventually the chaining looks pretty good. +1 for the code sample `checkName`, etc. ...Is there really no other options than to have something returned from the checks, though ?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same thing as I was writing it, the `if (compBoolean) Some(klass) else None` is pretty ugly and doesn't feel very idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

Using Option with filter would allow you to have the checks simply return a boolean value. For example

```
def checkName(klass: Klass): Boolean = ???
def checkVars(klass: Klass): Boolean = ???
def checkMethods(klass: Klass): Boolean = ???
def finalOp(klass: Klass): OutputClass = ???

Option(klass)
  .filter(checkName)
  .filter(checkVars)
  .filter(checkMethods)
  .map(finalOp)
```

You'll be left with `Some()` if all the checks passed, `None` if any of them failed.

Comment: The defined predicate functions are just for readability, you can just have the complex conditions in the filter calls directly as a lambda.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense than my answer

Comment: Indeed. I like the idea of returning `Boolean` from the checks. This makes sense. +1

Comment: @Julien__ [just as an FYI](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

```
program.classes foreach {
  case klass if checkName(klass) => error1
  case klass if checkVars(klass) => error2
  case klass if checkMethods(klass) => error3
  case klass => addToContext(klass)
}
```

Comment: Your answer is too brief.  Please give some explanation as to why it should be done this way

Comment: Smart... Perhaps even too smart ^^ +1 for the interesting idea though.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question using Partial Function composition (as the question asks), we define each check as a `PartialFunction`. We are also using a `Try` as a result type. `Try` can then preserve the specific error information that may arise during processing. *(`Option`, which seems a popular choice, does not preserve the reason why an element could not be found. I would not use it to implement a check unless we really don't care for any error information.)*

Simplified example:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val check1:PartialFunction[Int, Try[String]] = {case x if x==1 => Failure(new Exception("error1"))}
val check2:PartialFunction[Int, Try[String]] = {case x if x==2 => Failure(new Exception("error2"))}
val check3:PartialFunction[Int, Try[String]] = {case x if x==3 => Failure(new Exception("error3"))}
val process: PartialFunction[Int, Try[String]] = {case x => Success(s"[$x] processed OK")}

val checks = check1 orElse check2 orElse check3 orElse process

for (i <- 1 to 4) yield (checks(i))
//  scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.util.Try[String]] = Vector(
//    Failure(java.lang.Exception: error1),
//    Failure(java.lang.Exception: error2),
//    Failure(java.lang.Exception: error3),
//    Success([4] processed OK)
//)
```

Comment: Very interesting (+1) , but I need to chain on success, not on failure

Comment: @Julien__ This method "chains" on success and exists on failure. Note how the process passes each check either until it fails (numbers 1-3)  or gets to the final `process` statement (#4).

Comment: Oh I see now. This is the "partial functions" version of liljerk answer. I find it disturbing because `orElse` is usually associated with failure cases. But here the partial function is not defined in case of success. There is an indirection layer. (It's kind of like saying "not false" instead of "true").

Comment: @Julien__ yes. @liljerk answer uses the canonical form of pattern matching and that is sufficient if your rules are static (you just need to change the return type for a `Try`) My answer aims to your question " extract each into its own function". Using `orElse` is like adding one case statement below of the previous (they are evaluated in order and at most one be executed)

Answer (score 0):

## Chain using Option's fold

You can use `Option`s `fold` method.

fold is defined like this in the standard library

```
final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: Int => B): B
```

This can be applied to any general use case. All you have to do is to return Option of something continuously. The chain break if any method returns None in the below case. In the below code you communicate to the next operation by sending Some or None as message.

```
def f1: Option[_] = ???
def f2: Option[_] = ???
def f3: Option[_] = ???

f1.fold[Option[Unit]](None)(_ => f2).fold[Option[Unit]](None)(_ => f3)
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> Option(1).fold[Option[Unit]](None)(_ => Some(println("hello"))).fold[Option[Unit]](None)(_ => Some(println("scala")))
hello
scala
res59: Option[Unit] = Some(())

scala> None.fold[Option[Unit]](None)(_ => Some(println("hello"))).fold[Option[Unit]](None)(_ => Some(println("scala")))
res60: Option[Unit] = None

scala> Option(1).fold[Option[Unit]](None)(_ => None).fold[Option[Unit]](None)(_ => Some(println("scala")))
res61: Option[Unit] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern I used a lot in C that is also applicable in Scala. I remembered it this morning. You can create an implicit method if you want to rename `&&` to `thenIfSuccess` or something similar (not shown).

It takes advantage of the fact that `&&` is lazy in its second argument.

---

```
def checkName(klass: Klass): Boolean = ???
def checkVars(klass: Klass): Boolean = ???
def checkMethods(klass: Klass): Boolean = ???
def finalOp(klass: Klass): Boolean = ???
```

---

```
// just chain the method calls :
checkName(cls) && checkVars(cls) && checkMethods(cls) && finalOp(cls)


// this will call each method in order and stop if one fails.
```

---

If you think about it, its very easy to read, a lot more than other answers using `fold`, `filter` or pattern matching. The `for` expression is also very easy to read imho but it forces you to return `Option[_]` which is not very natural.